# Python request module vs. urllib.request vs. javascript with JQuery/ajax In Production Environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, python-requests

I am writing a small program that consumes an API. The program is using Python with requests JSON and requests module. it makes a HTTP request and the API returns a json data. Then I will do something to the data.

it looks like this.

```
import json, requests

url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json'
params = {...}

resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
data = json.loads(resp.text)
#do something with data
```

However, I start to wonder about 3 specific questions about my choice of language and design:

1. Currently, It is obvious that I am the only one using this program but eventually if I publish this program that means more than one people will be using it. Should my choice of language and module differ when it comes to production environment?
2. why should I use the request module, why not `urllib.request` module? urllib module can also make http request.
3. Furthermore, why use Python? I am using Python because I am familiar with it. Maybe I can use this chance to learn JavaScript. I can use JQuery and AJAX to accomplish the same thing. Is there a better way? or it depends on what the program is for?

Any explanation is appreciated.

---

Bonus: This following question is broad so I don't expect the chosen answer to include for the following questions but it will be nice.

There are much more great languages, modules, and library that can be used to accomplish my desired task. Basically is there a best way to request JSON data from an API? or it depends on the circumstances? if so, how do circumstances should affect the choice of language and design? and what are the pros and cons?

Comment: Your questions are pretty broad - I'd suggest you try to narrow this down to a more specific, less opinion seeking question for it to be appropriate for SO.

Comment: I separated out the broad section into the bonus that is not required. I however would really appreciate it to know the 3 specific questions I ask

Comment: The advantage of using a higher-level library is to provide a simpler abstraction that will often do repetitive things for you, e.g. interpreting a response as json - `data = resp.json()` no need to `import json`.

Comment: @J.Doe Is your Python application a web application (another API?) or a desktop app?

Comment: @abagshaw I intend for it to be a web application. But I am curious as of how it is being a desktop app would affect what stack I choose to use?

Comment: @J.Doe, I was just wanting to clarify as you mentioned a growing number of simultaneous requests as a potential issue - and I wasn't sure if you meant to your app, or the Google API.

Comment: @abagshaw I see. I meant would simultaneous request be a potential issue for my app. But I think Mortz's answer it clarified that it won't. That is more of a server side problem.

Comment: Serving a Python web app with http://gunicorn.org/ can help with concurrency as it can serve new requests on separate threads automatically.

Comment: That is good to know. So gunicorn is something to keep in mind when it comes to facing production environment?

Answer (score 1):

1. Requests makes your life easier. Not by much in this case, but try writing the same thing using `urllib2`
2. You can use any language of your choice. If you intend to make this into some kind of a CLI or GUI, then JS will probably be better because your final application can then live at a web address. Or you can make a nice App using Kivy or CLICK and distribute it as a binary
3. Problems with multiple connections is a lookout for the server, not your app. The stack that you use for the backend will be the deciding factor that makes or breaks your app, not how many people end up using it simultaneously.

Comment: thanks, @Mortz. Can you please elaborate more on your last point? In what case the stack I choose to use will break my program?

Comment: I meant where does your API fetch data from. You'll run into performance issues if you use a massive text file as a backend data store for instance.